# Publishing app to google play - where is the demo account data?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, review

As of late, google play is "reviewing" new apps that were published to google play.

My app requires the reviewer to have a demo account, otherwise the user cannot go past the initial screen.

Where is the place that I provide the reviewer with the demo account?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Actually you could provide extra data for google play by follow the instructions bellow:

1. Login in your google play developer account.
2. In the left side menu click on Policy -> App Content
3. Check the radio button "All or some functionality is restricted"
4. Click on "Add new instructions".
5. After enter your data you will be able to edit it by click on link "Manage".

[image]
[image]

Actually in now days google will reject apps that don't fill the
credentials for testing purposes. See the rejection from google play when you don't inform the demo credentials.

[image]

Comment: it's so so so subtle..

Comment: As of recent, this is the correct answer, it wasnt so in 2020. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google play does not open the app at all, they run automated tests on it, that does not seem to include opening the app.

It took 3 days and change but it was approved.

Comment: In my case they seemed to have logged in and used it a bit.... but thnks for your comment